# Как передать данные в кастомную ячейку UITableViewCell перед тем, как она будет построена?

Tags: ios, swift

Мне нужно передать данные в ячейку при её создании в методе tableView.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as? LessonTableViewCell
       //  Внутри класса LessonTableViewCell ячейка заполняет саму себя переданными ей данными
      /*код*/
}
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Есть много способов передать данные.
Самый простой:
Объявляете массив внутри UIViewController:

```
var birds = [String]()
```

Вместо String вы можете использовать свой класс с данными.
Заполняете его где угодно, например в viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    birds = ["finch", "sparrow", "eagle"]
}
```

И используете:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as? LessonTableViewCell
   let item = birds[IndexPath.row]
   cell.textLabel.text = item
   return cell
}
```